# Drupal Upgrade 8.9.2 to 9.5.9 getting fatal error

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I want to upgrade an existing Drupal website which is 8.9.2 to 9.5.9. But it's getting error when I run `update.php` from browser:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The "router.route_provider" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead. in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->make() (line 275 of vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Container.php)
```

I copied core & vendor folders from new downloaded Drupal directory along with all root level files.

But still it's showing error to run `update.php`. What am I missing here?

Previously, I faced no issue while upgrading Drupal 7 to 8.9.2

**Server Environment**
Apache: 2.4
PHP: 7.2
MySQL: 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Open the services.yml file located in the sites/default directory of your Drupal installation.

Look for the line that defines the router.route_provider service. It should resemble something like this:

services:
router.route_provider: '@router.route_provider.old_name'
Modify the line to make the service definition public:

Change the code to this:

services:
router.route_provider:
public: true
alias: '@router.route_provider.old_name'

Save the services.yml file.

Retry running the update.php script in your browser to see if the error is resolved.

Comment: Thanks but services.yml file doesn't contain `router.route_provider` in the drupal 8.9.2 or 9.5.9 both.